# How do I make sure the Energy fire log continuosuly burns?

Tags: fireplace, firewood

I have started using wood fireplace, and I am not sure why, even after using a fire starter, the energy fire log doesn't maintain fire. At the end, it leaves a dark surface on the energy fire log as though the fire couldn't penetrate the fire log. Can you suggest a method to continuously burn energy fire log? Can I add some oil to the energy fire log?

I am using a [High energy fire log](https://www.coastalcountry.com/products/home-improvement/heating-cooling/heating-fuel/high-energy-fire-logs-2-pack-niel40216) and a [fire starter](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Duraflame-Fatwood-Fire-Starters-for-Firewood-or-Charcoal-125-Cu-ft/32468459).

Comment: Are you using just one log or breaking it in pieces?  Large wood/wood like pieces like the heat/fire from other pieces to burn.  One single piece does tend to smoulder or go out.

Comment: @crip659 I do not break the energy fire log into small pieces.  What are your thoughts on Pellet Fuel: https://www.coastalcountry.com/products/home-improvement/heating-cooling/heating-fuel/coastal-premium-pellet-fuel-40-lb-bag-pcffcppf

Comment: Works good in a pellet stove, do not think it will work in a fireplace.  I would try breaking that log in about three pieces.  When burning real wood logs, I found chopping one big log in three or more pieces burned much better.

Comment: Seems to me like your log never got lit, and the only thing actually burning was your fire starter. So when the starter ran out, so did the fire.

Comment: How are you arranging your kindling? You'll need to get the kindling going pretty well and ideally starting a bit of a draft in order to make enough heat to get the log going. If you haven't started a fire before, I suggest a trip to YouTube University.

Answer (score 1):

When getting a fire going, we start from something small (eg grass) and progressively move to larger items (twigs, sticks) and finally logs.  The reason being anything needs heat to burn.  So a small amount of heat (a match) is only able to set fire to something slightly larger (grass or a fire lighter).  Once that small thing is burning, we can then use it to light something a bit larger still (twigs or kindling), and so on.

In your case you have nothing between small kindling and big logs so there's not enough heat to light the big logs.  So either you need to find something in the middle (broken up logs, or some other wood) or simulate it by using a lot of kindling.  Tree logs come in different sizes so you can usually find something - a problem with manufactured logs is they're all the same size.

Also, make sure your don't have so much fuel that it's blocking the air flow to the fire.  It's sometimes better to introduce fuel piece by piece than add it all at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

A single log (of any sort) burns poorly and usually self-extinguishes. Two or three logs are typically required to have a fire that will continue burning, as the spaces between the logs (where the heat from one is reinforced and heats the other, and vice-versa) maintain adequate heat to keep the fire going. A slight gap is required to allow air to flow in and provide oxygen for the flame.

Scattering a fire is one way to put it out without dousing with water. A single log is already "scattered."

Assuming this is in your house, in a stove or fireplace, adding oil is **A Very Bad Idea** and may result in you being a lot colder, due to no longer having a house to be in once you burn it down. ***Do not use flammable liquids*** in a solid-fuel burning fireplace or stove..